# C# Multi-threaded app - structure?

Tags: c#, multithreading, structure

So, I'll make an application for checking links if they're accessible(live).
My question is how to make the threads "always busy". What I mean:
The app run 100 threads(created with FOR loop for example) with 100 different URLs. So when 1 of the threads finish it's job(check if URL is available) to get new URL and start again immediately. So the 100 threads will work non-stop till all URLs are checked.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: How many cores are you dealing with here? 100 threads is likely to be more counter productive than helpful.

Comment: Getting URLs is expensive and a single threaded application is likely to be IO bound but you may need to decrease the number of threads from 100 to get the most efficient code, you should test different numbers of threads. You should also try just a HEAD request, I'm guessing you don't actually care about the content of the page, just that it exists and the URL is valid.

Comment: For those, *who said/upvoted 100 thread is a terrible idea*: On my dual core 2GB RAM XP machine `Parallel.Foreach` never created more than 5 threads(unless I set `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`) and creating 100 threads resulted always ~30-40% faster operation. So don't leave everything to `Parallel.Foreach` . PS: My test code `WebClient wc = new WebClient();var s = wc.DownloadString(url); (google's home page)`

Comment: +1 for actually trying it.  Sure, if the operations are I/O bound, a large number of threads should help.  There are many factors, eg. the DNS server may not appreciate 200 lookups from one client - it may think that a DOS attack is under way:(

Comment: @MartinJames Of course, I just wanted show that while I/O bounds ops are done, 2 threads per cpu may not be enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the [Producer-Consumer Model](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3023/en). You have a pool of resources, that contains the list of urls to check, one thread can fill that pool, and your conumer threads can pull from that pool, if you have .NET 4 [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) does most of the work for you.

Using 100 threads also is very likely not going to be the optimum number of threads, just let the Task Parallel Library manage the thread count for you.

Here is a example if the list will be pre-populated and not have more items added as the thread is running.

```
//Parallel.Foreach will block until it is done so you may want to run this function on a background worker.
public void StartThreads()
{
    List<string> myListOfUrls = GetUrls();

    Parallel.Foreach(myListOfUrls, ProcessUrl);
}


private void ProcessUrl(string url)
{
    //Do your work here, this code will be run from multiple threads.
}
```

If you need to populate the collection as it runs, replace `List<string>` with a concurrent collection like [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779)

```
BlockingCollection<string> myListOfUrls = new BlockingCollection();

//Parallel.Foreach will block until it is done so you may want to run this function on a background worker.
public void StartThreads()
{
    if(myListOfUrls.IsComplete == true)
    {
        //The collection has emptied itself and you told it you where done using it, you will either need to throw a exception or make a new collection.
        //use IsCompleatedAdding to check to see if you told it that you are done with it, but there still may be members left to process.
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    //We create a Partitioner to remove the buffering behavior of Parallel.ForEach, this gives better performance with a BlockingCollection.
    var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(myListOfUrls.GetConsumingEnumerable(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
    Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, ProcessUrl);
}

public void StopThreads()
{
    myListOfUrls.CompletedAdding()
}

public void AddUrl(string url)
{
    myListOfUrls.Add(url);
}

private void ProcessUrl(string url)
{
    //Do your work here, this code will be run from multiple threads.
}
```

---

I also wanted to add that the automated thread scheduling may not be the best also, it may put some limits that could be expanded on, see this comment from the original question

> For those, who said/upvoted 100 thread is a terrible idea: On my dual
>   core 2GB RAM XP machine Parallel.Foreach never created more than 5
>   threads(unless I set ThreadPool.SetMinThreads) and creating 100
>   threads resulted always ~30-40% faster operation. So don't leave
>   everything to Parallel.Foreach . PS: My test code WebClient wc = new
>   WebClient();var s = wc.DownloadString(url); (google's home page) – [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b)

Comment: Good answer. Using PLinq, the machine can determine wheter it will use multiple threads for performance. +1 For referring to the Producer-Consumer Model.

Comment: Def wanna mention that 100 threads is a terrible idea. At most, two threads per core. With 100 threads, you're just making things worse than if you had no threads at all.

Comment: Hmm, that thing with the number of the threads intrigued me. Why is that?
I thought my problem was the internet connection.

PS: The answer with the producer-consumer model is all I need. Thanks!

Comment: @user1410644 You have to think about where the bottleneck is, if you are at 100% cpu throwing more threads at it wont solve the problem, if at 100 threads you are still stitting at idle because all of the queires are waiting on a networked servers you need more threads. The Parallel.Foreach manages both situations for you, it will make as many threads as it needs, be it 2 or 2000. The only place it wont help you is if you are at idle, but the thing you are waiting on is saturated with requests so more requests won't help, Reading a files from the hard disk is a good example of this problem.

Comment: Can I add more parameters to ProcessUrl() and how to pass them?

Comment: @user1410644 Yes, but not as easy as you might think, Look at the MSDN pages for the overloads of Parallel.ForEach, if you need further help, do not hesitate to open a new question.

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge - then my machine is in trouble now - Kapersky and Sidebar have 133 threads between them.  'System' has 241.  200 threads is nothing.  The bottleneck is likely to be DNS lookup performance.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, but those threads are just sitting there waiting. All 100 of his threads will be trying to hit the CPU for processing power all the time. That's where the problem would be. You can start as many threads as you want, and if they are all in a wait state, then nothing is going to bog down the CPU, but if those threads are all fighting for the CPU, then you have a problem.

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge -  the OP is doing mostly synchronous DNS lookups - next to no CPU use because the threads are blocked on network I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Parallel CTP stuff, the parallel foreach method included will do exactly what you want.

Google is your friend.

Also, using 100 threads may not be best for performance, I would use however many cores are available.

Comment: From what I've read, seems that two threads per core is standard.

Comment: So the problem with the threads is if the app is parallelized or generally?

Comment: You do know that CTP meant "Community Tech Preview"?  It was how Microsoft originally released the 'beta' version.  This is now fully released as the PLINQ and Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @RayHayes - Yes, but the OP didn't state .NET version.

Comment: @Marlon, all the more reason to make it clear which version the functionality is available in.  Indeed, the CTP means installing an out of date upgrade to an old version of .NET!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ThreadPool` and give it the list of urls to process, then let a `DoWork` method handle the checking of whether they are live or not, e.g.

```
 foreach (string s in URLs)
 {
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), s);
 }

 public void DoWork(object sender)
 {
       string url = (string)sender;
       //do stuff with url here
  }
```